# (Action<T>).Name does not return expected values

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have the following method (used to generate friendly error messages in unit tests):

```
protected string MethodName<TTestedType>(Action<TTestedType> call)
{
    return string.Format("{0}.{1}", typeof(TTestedType).FullName, call.Method.Name);
}
```

But when I call it as follows, I don't get the expected results:

```
var nm = MethodName<MyController>(ctrl => ctrl.Create());
```

After running this code, `nm` contains `"<Create_CreateShowsView>b__8"`, and not (as expected) `"Create"`. How should I change the code to obtain the expected result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass an `Expression` instead of an `Action`.  It's actually not that hard to use expression trees for this once you understand what the tree looks like.

The line of code:

```
(MyClass c) => c.TestMethod();
```

Can be broken down as as a lambda expression (the entire block), containing one parameter (`c`, on the left side), and a body (`c.TestMethod()`, on the right side).

Then the "body" is a method call on a specific object (which is the parameter, `c`), an actual method (`TestMethod`), and a set of arguments (in this case, there aren't any).

Visually:

```
            LambdaExpression   [ (MyClass c) => c.TestMethod() ]
             /           \
            /             \
           /               \
      Parameters          Body   [ MethodCallExpression: c.TestMethod() ]
          |              /    \
          |             /      \
    1: MyClass c    Object [c]  \
                                /\
                               /  \
                              /    \
             Method [TestMethod]  Arguments [Empty]
```

What you want is the method name, inside the method call expression, inside the body of the lambda expression.  So the code to get this is:

```
static string GetInnerMethodName<T>(Expression<Action<T>> expr)
{
    MethodCallExpression mce = expr.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    return (mce != null) ? mce.Method.Name : null;
}
```

Of course, this will only work if the `Expression<Action<T>>` passed in is a genuine method call expression; the consumer of this method could technically pass in any expression, in which case this will just return `null`.  You can adjust this to throw an exception instead, return a default value, or perform whatever other action you think is appropriate.

You don't need to do anything special to use this - it's the same usage as your original method:

```
string methodName = GetInnerMethodName<MyClass>(c => c.TestMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

That `b__8` thing is the name of the method that is generated by the C# compiler for your lambda.  You can see this by using [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/), for instance.

If you need it to say "Create", you'll have to actually make a method named `Create`.  And of course it needs to fit into an `Action`, so it will have to return `void`.

---

In simple cases, you could create a method that takes a string indicating a method to be called, and return an action that calls that method on an object of a specified type.  See for instance [this tutorial](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ:_How_call_a_method_using_a_name_string).

Comment: OK. Is there any way I can get the name *I* chose in the code instead of the CLR name of the method?

Comment: @Tomas: It's an anonymous function, so it has no name. The method isn't actually `Create`, it's "an unnamed method that takes a `TTestedType` as a parameter and calls its `Create` method."

Comment: @Aaron - you're right, of course. That was something I had overlooked... Is there any way I can get to "Create" from that anonymous method?

Comment: I'm no reflection expert in C#, but you should be able to pass in the string "Create" and use reflection to create an action of form `x => x.Create()`.  We'll see what the other answers come up with.

Comment: If not, how do I create a named method? I tried assigning the lambda expression to a variable named Create, but still got the wierd b__8 stuff...

Comment: @Mark: The reason this problem came up was that I wanted a strongly typed way of getting the method name - I wouldn't need this method at all if passing the string "Create" around was an option... :P

Comment: @Reed: OK... Never used them before. Do you have a good link to a quick-start-place? =)

Comment: @Tomas: If you take an `Expression<Action<TTestedType>>` instead of an `Action<TTestedType>` then you can parse it as a `LambdaExpression`, with the `Body` being a `MethodCallExpression`, from which you can get the "real" `Method`.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Sounds cool. But I have no clue how to do it... Care to show me?